# pg_rman backup stuck in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue with pg_rman backup stuck in database postgresql version 14.3.

backup command:

```
pg_rman backup --backup-mode=full --with-serverlog
INFO: copying database files
```

```
 pg_rman show
=====================================================================
 StartTime           EndTime              Mode    Size   TLI  Status
=====================================================================
2023-06-07 15:20:04  1970-01-01 07:00:00  FULL      0B     0  RUNNING
```

I installed `pg_rman` by source. I cannot find any logs to check it. Could you please help to support it?